# [Excel][VBA] How to draw a line in a graph?

Tags: vba, graph, excel, draw

Please view this image to get my clearly question:
[image]

Comment: Could you try to post a higher resolution graphic or elaborate on your question?  The image's resolution does not make your question clear.

Comment: @Jubbles: I updated, please help!

Comment: Just add a second series to the plot, using the required coordinates.  You only need two points.

Comment: I can't do follow you! Would you give me a sample?

Answer (score 6):

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim s, d

    d = #4/18/2011# * 1 ''a bit of a hack, since I could figure out how to plot a date directly
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart 'adjust to suit

        Set s = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
        With s
            .Name = ""
            .XValues = Array(d, d)
            .Values = Array(90, 0)
            .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
            .Border.Color = vbRed
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim Wiliams: It's don't work, the line not meet my requriment (it's oblique)

Comment: @hungbm06: This works fine! Just tried it myself. @Tim: +1 for teaching me something I didn't know, namely that you can feed litteral Arrays (and not just sheet ranges) to XValues and Values.

Comment: @hungbm06: Might be a problem with your locale. Instead of `d = #4/18/2011# * 1`, try `Dim d As Double` followed by `d = DateSerial(2011, 4, 18)`.

Comment: @hungbm06: Aha. I just reproduced your problem. See @Jon Peltier's answer for the solution. You have to change your chart type from a Line chart to an XY (scatter) chart. Generally, I find XY charts easier to manipulate and more difficult to screw up.

Answer (score 3):

Excellll's answer is incomplete. If you simply add this data to what is obviously a LINE chart, it will not appear where intended. You have to convert the added series to an XY chart series (right click on the series, Chart Type).

Also, your line falls midway between 4/17 and 4/18, so you need to use noon on 4/17 as the X value, that is 4/17/11 12:00.

Here is a set of articles about adding lines to Excel charts:
http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AddLine.html

Also, deleting the legend entry is done by selecting the text of the legend entry and pressing Delete. This takes two single clicks on the legend entry, not one double click.

Comment: Your solution is only correct if x-axis is date, it wrong with other type of x-axis

Comment: If it's another type of axis, you can use different X values for the line you need to add.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind extra clutter in your workbook you can fill four cells with the following:

```
4/18/11     0
4/18/11    90
```

Add a new series to the chart with this data.  If you don't want the new series to show up in the chart legend, then double-click on the red series name in the legend and press 'Delete'.